# How to embed xaml from another folder in xmal

Tags: xaml, uwp

[project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sb1S.png)

Hello. I have main XAML UWP View (MainTabbar.xaml) and Tab content view (MethodTabView.xaml). MethodTabView.xaml located in another folder. I need to embed MethodTabView.xaml within MainTabbar.xaml. Everything embeds fine if both files are in the same folder, but if files located in different folders, it doesn't working. Please help

Comment: Could you please share the code about how you use the xaml file? It will be better if you could share more details about what you are trying to get and what you are doing now.

Comment: I have XAML Page (MainTabbar.xaml) and XAML Page (or UserControl) in another children folder. I need to embed XAML Page in XAML Page.  Now i embed page in page from same directory by connect '<xmls:name="using:Name">' in header, but it doesn't working if I trying to connect page from children directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use the xaml control that you've created in another folder, right?

You will need to add references to the Page. I think you might change a little bit for your code.

I've made a simple demo and you could refer to it. I created a new Folder called `MethodFolder`, then I created a new UserControl called `TestUserControl`. After that, I added the reference to the page where I want to use the user control. Like:

```
 xmlns:Name="using:ProjectName.FolderName"
```

So here is the code that I'm using:

```
<Page
x:Class="TestReference.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestReference"
xmlns:MethodFolder="using:TestReference.MethodFolder"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <MethodFolder:TestUserControl />
</Grid>
```

And this is the screenshot of my project:

[image]

Comment: It is right solution. Thank you!